# Problemas com Json e php

Tags: php, json

Meu código deveria pegar dados do banco, e atribuir a um array, porém, quando listo esse array, os dados não entram nos campos

```
<?php
include_once '../../classes/Conexao.php';
use classes\Conexao;
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');

$id_veiculo = "1654641106";
$cpf = "25836914766";

$conn = new Conexao();
$link = $conn->getLink();

$select = "SELECT veiculo.PLACA , veiculo.NOME as    NOME_VEICULO,cliente.NOME as NOME_CLIENTE,cliente.TELEFONE FROM `veiculo`  INNER join cliente on veiculo.CPF = cliente.CPF WHERE cliente.CPF =$cpf AND veiculo.ID_CARRO =$id_veiculo ";
$resultado_consulta = mysqli_query($link, $select);

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_consulta) )
{
 echo $row['NOME_CLIENTE'];
 echo "<BR>";
 echo $row['NOME_VEICULO'];
 echo "<BR>";
 echo $row['TELEFONE'];
 echo "<BR>";
 echo $row['PLACA'];
}
$resultado[] = array(
 'nome_cliente' =>$row['NOME_CLIENTE'],
 'cpf' =>$cpf,
 'telefone' =>$row['TELEFONE'],
'nome_veiculo' =>$row['NOME_VEICULO'],
 'placa' =>$row['PLACA'],
 );
echo(json_encode($resultado));
?>
```

Essa listagem eu fiz apenas para me certificar de que o query estava funcionando, e está, mas a atribuição ao array não roda. o resultado desse código fica assim[[image: 1]]
Note que o valor da variável $cpf que foi iniciada no começo do código é atribuído, mas o resultado da consulta não

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possivelmente porque você esta definindo o array fora do loop `while()`, tenta assim:

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_consulta) )
{
    $resultado[] = array(
     'nome_cliente' =>$row['NOME_CLIENTE'],
     'cpf' =>$cpf,
     'telefone' =>$row['TELEFONE'],
    'nome_veiculo' =>$row['NOME_VEICULO'],
     'placa' =>$row['PLACA'],
     );
}
echo(json_encode($resultado));
```

Comment: Pois é, depois que perguntei que vi que era por isso, mas obrigado pela atenção viu

Comment: Eu quem agradeço por poder ajudar